# How to respect spaces when passing body to an mailto in C#

Tags: c#, url, mailto

I've got a Template style page which build a mailto link to open a prebuilt email in the users default mail client

I realise that using URLencode by default will replace spaces with + ( and pathencode will replace with %20 ) - but is it possible to pass a body and subject to a mailto while respecting spaces in the content? - for example, in javascript using encodeURIComponent(yourMessage) will retain the spaces within the "yourmessage" variable

```
   private void SubmitEmail(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
    string txt = "text that is an example";
    string rnt = "this is also an example";
    string PrioStr = "this is an example, of text that will come from a radio buttons contents";
    var yourMessage = txt;
    var subject =$"firstvariable:{Rnt}     secondvariable:{PrioStr}";

    var url =$"mailto:test@test.com.com?subject={HttpUtility.UrlEncode(subject)}&body={HttpUtility.UrlEncode(yourMessage)}"; 

     Process.Start(url);
     }
```

- this is a conversion of something i've already built using javascript which works as expected in javascript but when applying the logic to C# it replaces spaces in the subject/body with '+' symbols

Comment: Hi @NineBerry  Sorry, i missed out the process.start that runs the actual URL! My bad - I've made some amendments to make it a little bit more complete This occurs as part of a button Click in a WPF form, if that helps?

Comment: What email application are you testing? Outlook (2015) seems to be able to handle spaces escaped as `%20`.

Comment: I've used Outlook 2013, and windows 10's default "mail" client connected to a gmail account

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `Uri.EscapeDataString`, which will escape spaces as `%20`.

```
private void SubmitEmail(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    string txt = "text that is an example";
    string rnt = "this is also an example";
    string PrioStr = "this is an example, of text that will come from a radio buttons contents";
    var yourMessage = txt;
    var subject =$"firstvariable:{Rnt}     secondvariable:{PrioStr}";

    var url = $"mailto:test@test.com.com?subject={Uri.EscapeDataString(subject)}&body={Uri.EscapeDataString(yourMessage)}";
}
```

Comment: This worked exactly how i needed it to! Thank you so much!